# Numbered lists not showing up when i download jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am writing some explanations for some code and had to list all the functions as a numbered list in a Markdown cell. While the numbers seem to be showing in the .ipynb format, it is not showing up correctly when downloaded in .html format. (Pls refer to attached to photos).

[Numbered list in the .ipynb format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWjKB.png)

[Numbered list in the .html format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cu2e.png)

Comment: please don't post code as photos...

Comment: @mb21 It's not the code that I want to show. It's the numbered lists that I want to draw everyone's attention to. In the .ipynb format, the numbered lists are rendered correctly but when I download it as a .html format I am not getting the correct numbered list.